# Displaying guessed letters using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am toying around creating a guessing game which gives a user a certain amount of tries to guess the correct letter using Javascript and HTML.

When they guess, I would like to have their previous guessed letters show on screen.

However, it shows commas when the user types in the wrong letters.

In summary, I thought the following would suffice :

```
var guessedLetters = []; //Array to capture user letter input
var yourGuess = event.key; //variable to capute user's guess
guessedLetters.push(yourGuess); //This is suppose to capture letters entered by the user
.
.
.
"<p>Guessed Letter: " +  guessedLetters.join(', '); //Show guessed letters here
```

Please note that the win/loss portion is still being worked on...and yes I am a noob to Javascript :)

Below is the code I have so far (comments have been made for understanding code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>The Guessing Game</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="psychicAct">
    <h1>The Guessing Game</h1>
    <p>Guess what letter I'm thinking of:</p>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var psychicLetters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
  var youWin = 0;
  var youLose = 0;
  var guessesLeft = 13;
  var guessedLetters = []; //Array to capture user letter input

  document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    var yourGuess = event.key; //variable to capute user's guess
    guessedLetters.push(yourGuess); //This is suppose to capture letters     entered by the user    
    var psychicAns = psychicLetters[Math.floor(Math.random() *    psychicLetters.length)];

    //If your guess matches the psychic's guess,
    //a point is added to the "Wins" tally and the guesses tally restarts.
    if (yourGuess === psychicAns) {
      youWin++;
      guessesLeft = 12;
    }
    //If your does not not match the psychic's guess, your number of  guesses remaining are deducted.
    else {
      guessesLeft--;
    }

    //If the guesses remaining equals 0, you lose, an increment is added to  the "Losses" tally and the points restart.
    if (guessesLeft === 0){
      youLose++;
      guessesLeft = 12;
    }

    var html = "<p>Guess what letter I'm thinking of:</p>" + "<p>Wins: " + youWin + "</p>" + "<p>Loses: "+ youLose + "<p>Guesses Remaining: " + guessesLeft + "<p>Guessed Letter: " +  guessedLetters.join(', '); //Show guessed letters here
    document.querySelector("#psychicAct").innerHTML = html;
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some indents to your code.... unreadable currently

Comment: Perhaps drop this into a fiddle for easier experimentation?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q1uxvq8b/ - it seems to work fine as it is. If you don't want commas to appear, then remove the comma from `guessedLetters.join(', ');` - just use `guessedLetters.join(' ');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a simplified code. I created different functions to make it more readable and clear thus you can understand easier.

```js
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
var wins = 0;
var loses = 0;
var guessesLeft, guessedLetters, letterToGuess;

resetGame();
display();

document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  var guess = event.key;
  if (guess === letterToGuess) {
    win();
  } else if (guessesLeft - 1 === 0) {
    lost();
  } else {
    fail(guess);
  }

  display();
}

function display() {
  var winsP = document.getElementById("wins");
  var losesP = document.getElementById("loses");
  var guessLeft = document.getElementById("guessLeft");
  var letterGuessed = document.getElementById("guessed");
  winsP.innerHTML = wins;
  losesP.innerHTML = loses;
  guessLeft.innerHTML = guessesLeft;
  letterGuessed.innerHTML = guessedLetters.join(',');
}

function win() {
  wins++;
  resetGame();
}

function lost() {
  loses++;
  resetGame();
}

function fail(letter) {
  guessesLeft--;
  guessedLetters.push(letter);
}

function resetGame() {
  guessesLeft = 12;
  guessedLetters = [];
  letterToGuess = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
  console.log("Letter to guess: " + letterToGuess);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>The Guessing Game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="psychicAct">
    <h1>The Guessing Game</h1>
    <h3>Wins:
      <p id="wins"></p>
    </h3>
    <h3>Loses:
      <p id="loses"></p>
    </h3>
    <h3>Guess left:
      <p id="guessLeft"></p>
    </h3>
    <p>Guess what letter I'm thinking of:</p>
    <p id="guessed"></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! And thanks for the tips in braking into functions (much easier to read). How would I bring both the HTML code and the javascript code together since they are now separate. I tried but it seems like this part is not working on my computer.

Comment: Simply add the javascript inside `<script>[insert here]</script>`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes I did include the <script>javascript</script>, but  I am unable to get it to work. I am assuming the <!Doctype html> HTML code </html> does not go in the <script><script> section?

Comment: @EDavidson only script goes in the script section. doctype is markup. The snippet is clearly divided up into script (first section) and markup (second section), it seems pretty clear what to do. And when you say "unable to work", it would be more helpful to discuss what console errors / unexpected behaviour you get, instead of just saying it's broken :-)

Comment: Javascript inside `script` tag and HTML outside of it.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for being vague about it nor working. When I type any letter, nothing it shown on the screen. Meaning the HTML content is shown, but it the JavaScript seems like it is not working like the example above. And  yes I did put <script> around the JavaScript and <HTML>  markup around the HTML code.  Sorry for being a pain :(

Comment: @EDavidson when nothing is shown on the page (as you type), is there any error shown in the browser console?

Comment: Thanks for the reply....stupid me. As soon as I put the code into Dreamweaver the code lit up like a Christmas tree. There were several semicolons missing, and soeme code was missing. I decided to separate the script into its own file to read easier, and now adding CSS to make it look better. I appreciate all of your help @ADyson and @Weedoze!

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. you need a placeholder to show the results.
2. several closing tags in the `html` variable are missing
3. you need to find that placeholder and display the result when the results change:

```html
  <div id="psychicAct">
    <h1>The Guessing Game</h1>    
    <div id="results"><p>Guess what letter I'm thinking of:</p></div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var psychicLetters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
    var youWin = 0;
    var youLose = 0;
    var guessesLeft = 13;
    var guessedLetters = []; //Array to capture user letter input
    document.onkeyup = function(event) {
      var yourGuess = event.key; //variable to capute user's guess
      guessedLetters.push(yourGuess); //This is suppose to capture letters     entered by the user    
      var psychicAns = psychicLetters[Math.floor(Math.random() * psychicLetters.length)];
      //If your guess matches the psychic's guess,
      //a point is added to the "Wins" tally and the guesses tally restarts.
      if (yourGuess === psychicAns) {
        youWin++;
        guessesLeft = 12;
      }
      //If your does not not match the psychic's guess, your number of  guesses  remaining are deducted.
      else {
        guessesLeft--;
      }
      //If the guesses remaining equals 0, you lose, an increment is added to  the "Losses" tally and the points restart.
      if (guessesLeft === 0) {
        youLose++;
        guessesLeft = 12;
      }
      var html = "<p>Guess what letter I'm thinking of:</p>" +
        "<p>Wins: " + youWin + "</p>" +
        "<p>Loses: " + youLose + "</p>" +
        "<p>Guesses Remaining: " + guessesLeft + "</p>" +
        "<p>Guessed Letter: " + guessedLetters.join(', ') + "</p>" ; //Show guessed     letters heredocument.querySelector("#psychicAct").innerHTML = html;
        
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = html;
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Note you'll need to click on the example output above to give it focus before it will accept the keyboard input